# BigQuery Command Line - List all jobs that were run with a specified time range

Tags: linux, google-bigquery, jobs

I know that in order to get a list of all the jobs that were ever run in a Google account, you would need to run the following command:

```
Command 1: bq ls --format json --jobs --all
```

In order to get some n number of results only, you can add another parameter called max_results

```
Command 2: bq ls --format json --jobs --all --max_results
```

How about the case where I want to get the number of jobs between two dates? Which parameter(s) should I further add to the first command? Looked through the documentation but could not find much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get information about jobs run at a particular time is to enable Google Cloud [audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/), set up [export](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export#creating_export_destinations) to bigquery, then run a query over the logs.

The query would look something like:

```
SELECT metadata.timestamp as job_complete_time,
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobName.jobId 
    AS job_id,
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.query 
    AS query,
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
    [audit_logs.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_],
    DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -14, "DAY"), 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
WHERE metadata.serviceName = 'bigquery.googleapis.com'
    AND protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.query 
    is not null
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: is there a way to do this if there was not audit logging enabled yet?